# How to pass a pipe command to terminal -e?

Tags: terminal, make, urxvt, tee

I want to create a shortcut which shows in a new terminal the output of my command and simultaneously writes it into a log file.
I use terminal -e (or urxvt -e) to run the follwing command:

```
terminal -e make -j4 | tee log.log
```

But the problem is, it interprets the pipe as a local pipe instead of directing it to the new terminal. 
But when I use

```
terminal -e "make -j4 | tee log.log"
```

it seams to interpret | as a character. evenm when I escape it with \|.
So whats the solution here? I simply want to run a piped command in  a new terminal window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
urxvt -e sh -c "make -j4 | tee log.log"
```